# Add a dynamic variable in array into a jQuery function

Tags: jquery, arrays, variables

Hi here I have a array variable links. I have to add the value for `keywords` and `label`  dynamically. How do you add this? Thank you

**update**

**MyIssue** I need to add(push) the value for keyword and labels dynamically in that Array for autocomplete. How to do this?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>jQuery UI Autocomplete - Default functionality</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://jqueryui.com/themes/base/jquery.ui.all.css">
     <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="../js/cordova-1.7.0.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="../js/jquery-1.7.2.js"></script>

    <script src="http://jqueryui.com/ui/jquery.ui.core.js"></script>
    <script src="http://jqueryui.com/ui/jquery.ui.widget.js"></script>
    <script src="http://jqueryui.com/ui/jquery.ui.position.js"></script>
    <script src="http://jqueryui.com/ui/jquery.ui.autocomplete.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://jqueryui.com/demos/demos.css">
    <script>
    $(function() {
        var links = [
        {
            keywords: ['create', 'add', 'make', 'insert', 'user'],
            label: "Create user",
            //desc: "Create a user in the system",
            //url: 'http://mysite.com/user/create/'
        },
        {
            keywords: ['create', 'add', 'make', 'insert', 'organisation'],
            label: "Create organisation",
           // desc: "Create an organisation in the system",
           // url: 'http://mysite.com/organisation/create/'
        }];
        $( "#tags" ).autocomplete({

             source: function(request, response) {  
             var matched = [];

        for (var k = 0; k < links.length; k++) {
            if (checkSearchWordsMatchKeywords(request.term, links[k]['keywords'])) {
                matched.push(links[k]);
            }
        }
        // display the filtered results
        response(matched);

             } 
        });

        function checkSearchWordsMatchKeywords(searchWords, keywords)
        {
            var searchWords = searchWords.toLowerCase();    // Lowercase the search words
            var searchWords = searchWords.split(' ');       // Break up the search into separate words
            var numOfSearchWords = searchWords.length;      // Count number of search words
            var numOfKeywords = keywords.length;            // Count the number of keywords
            var matches = [];                               // Will contain the keywords that matched the search words

            // For each search word look up the keywords array to see if the search word partially matches the keyword
            for (var i = 0; i < numOfSearchWords; i++)
            {
                // For each keyword
                for (var j = 0; j < numOfKeywords; j++)
                {   
                    // Check search word is part of a keyword
                    if (keywords[j].indexOf(searchWords[i]) != -1)
                    {
                        // Found match, store match, then look for next search word
                        matches.push(keywords[j]);
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
            if (matches.length == numOfSearchWords)
            {

                return true;
            }
            }

    });
    </script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="demo">

<div class="ui-widget">
    <label for="tags">Tags: </label>
    <input id="tags" />
</div>

</div><!-- End demo -->

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: i need to add the value dynamically for keywords and label

Comment: How do you decide exactly which keyword array you want to add values into?

Comment: i have some value in database for keyword and label.Is it possible to add the value?

Comment: Yes it is possible :) .. See there are two keywords arrays in your question, my question is, how do you decide in which array you want to add new value?

Comment: for example here i have value ['create', 'add', 'make', 'insert', 'user'] is "0th position" in keywords similar that in label: "Create user" is "0th" position...i need to add like that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

General way is (provided you know the index of keyword array),

```
links[index].keywords[links[index].keywords.length] = "your new value";
```

and

```
links[index].label = "your new label value";
```

Let us know how do you determine `index` value,so that we can help you in more specific way :)

Comment: Thank you for reply ...index starts from zero ,,links[index].keywords[links[index].keywords.length] = "your new value";  i dont understand this line

Comment: Its like, `links[index].keywords` will select the keyword array... `links[index].keywords[links[index]. Keywords.length ]` will give you the length of that selected array. And you will add the new element at the end if that keywords array...

Answer (score 2):

to add a new label

```
newLabel = { "keywords":[], "label":"Empty Label" };
links.push(newLabel);
```

to add to keywords, you will need to iterate through the links array

```
$(links).each(function(){ if(this["label"] = "Empty Label") { this["keywords"].push("newKeyword") } });
```

the above code is considering you want to add to keywords of the "Empty Label" Label

Answer (score 0):

Set the keys and label as variables, then add the keys to the label's index in the array:

```
var links = new Array();
var keys = ['create', 'add', 'make', 'insert', 'user'];
var label = "Create user";

links[label] = keys;

alert(links["Create user"]);
```

The alert: `create,add,make,insert,user`